# What was the origin of the meme where Batman slaps Robin?

Tags: dc, batman, history-of, robin, meme

I have seen the meme of Batman slapping Robin so many times. I really want to know the origin of it. When did it occur in the comics, and why did he even slap him?

<sub>Note: Spoilers are welcome.</sub>

Answer (score 72, accepted):

As recorded in [knowyourmeme.com](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/my-parents-are-dead-batman-slapping-robin):

> According to the Comics Should Be Good Archive, the panel originated from the 1965 comic book “World’s Finest #153.” The story is based around an alternate reality in which Batman believes that Superboy and Superman are responsible for the death of his father.

[image]

Comment: "Hey Batman, what'd your parents get you for Christm-""MY PARENTS ARE DEEEEEEAD!"

Comment: Considering the plot of the upcoming Superman vs Batman film, it looks like poor Supes has always been distrusted by Batman.

Comment: @TylerH It's not just Supe's. Batman has been shown on multiple occasions to keep samples of the weakness of *Every single member of the justice league* (Bat's has been frequently shown to carry kryptonite in a lead lined pouch of his utility belt as all times). Recently in the new 52 he has a bunker in the middle east with neat little boxes with each members logo on them containing their weaknesses. Interestingly enough, Wonder Woman's box is actually empty, and Bats is relying on Supe's if WW goes on the warpath.

Comment: @Sidney Superman vs Wonder Woman? I can't wait for *that* DCAU movie; here's hoping...

Comment: @TylerH They haven't done that specifically, but check out *Flashpoint* for a chilling example of what Wonder Woman-as-antagonist can be like...

Comment: @MasonWheeler Yes, I've seen the DCAU movie of that, The Flashpoint Paradox. To a lesser extent, there's also Justice League: Doom, where each of the JL members are targeted with intimate knowledge of their specific weaknesses, Wonder Woman included.

Comment: Funnily, the image in the meme is often reversed (with Batman on the right) compared to the comics.